# XCode linker issues with code in CPP file

Tags: xcode, cocoa, objective-c++

I'm having some frustration with XCode and a very simple project.

- I have a Cocoa application with all the .m files renamed to .mm so it can compile CPP files.
- I have a static library to store all my C++ code.
- I have a simple class with the header in the .h file, and the definition in the .cpp file.

I'm getting the errors in the vain of 'Undefined symbols for architecture'.

What is strange is that if I put all the code in the header file, it will work. I can have both the definition in the header AND CPP file, and it won't complain about redefining functions. It's as if it doesn't see that the CPP file exist.

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

**Edit**: If I move the c++ object from the library into the main project then it all works. It's something to do with the classes being in the static library.

**Edit 2**:

Specific details. There's nothing really complicated about the code.

In the main project, there is the main View class. In the awakeFromNib:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    MyCat aCat();
}
```

In the static library, I have MyCat.cpp and MyCat.h.

In the header file (MyCat.h)

```
class MyCat
{
public:
    MyCat();
};
```

In the CPP file (MyCat.cpp)

```
#include "MyCat.h"

MyCat::MyCat()
{
}
```

Error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyCat::MyCat()", referenced from:
      -[MainView awakeFromNib] in MainView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

If I don't use the class then the project compiles fine. If I put all the C++ code in the header file, it will compile fine. If I move the C++ file into the main project, out of the static library, it will again compile fine.

Comment: Update your question with specific details.

Comment: i suspect it's not building the mm files. make sure they are included in the target you are building.

Comment: All the .mm files are accounted for in the Compile Sources section.

Comment: May be library doesn't linked with project. Or library doesn't compiled for x86_64.